# XMLHttpRequest doesn't work from .js

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have this code that I want to use to pass information to a php file:

```
<script>
var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhttp.open("GET", "page.php?sess=123123", true);
xhttp.overrideMimeType('text/xml; charset=UTF-8');
xhttp.send(null);
</script>
```

If i echo this code in my .php page, it works on page load ("page.php" recieves the sess variable and stores it). However, when I copy this code (without the script tag) into a .js file that I use in my main php page, it doesn't work.

The idea is that I want to pass sess parameter to page.php when a specific javascript based timer is triggered.

Your help is appreciated.

Comment: It makes no difference whatsoever (other than a small timing change which won't have any effect on the above) whether you put the code in an inline script like the above or in a separate `.js` resource, if you link the resource correctly. So the problem is that it's not being linked correctly. It would matter if you had PHP code mixed in (e.g., `<?php ... ?>`), but you don't in the code you've quoted.

Comment: you did not forget to included the link to the js file?

Comment: you need to set request header too.
 XMLHttpRequest.setRequestHeader()

Comment: It was indeed the linking... both files are located in the same folder, for some reason in php it worked for page.php and in .js it worked after i changed it to /folder/page.php. Thanks !

Comment: Suggest deleting the question, it won't be useful to others in the future. Glad you figured it out!

Comment: @Jain: No you don't, not unless you have some specific request header you want to set.

Comment: Yep, I missed that it auto detects headers too.